# What if users change the css of hidden elements that should only appear after login?

Tags: php, css

so i am currently working on a website , and when the user logs in, buttons like : profile (that points to the users profile) and logout are displayed if the login was successfully, but someone could change the css and make these buttons appear and that would cause some php errors when cliked since no user is logged in. 
 Should i hidde, show elements with other methods than css like javaScript or should i handle all this possible errors in php ?

Comment: How about not displaying HTML that shouldn't be displayed if the user isn't logged in.

Comment: And I suggest doing this server side (PHP, in your case)

Comment: `What if users change the css of hidden elements that should only appear after login` then they will be able to see them, no?  As others state, don't send anything to the client they should not see, ever .. can't trust them and their greasy paws.... lol

Comment: @shadow only problem with that is some errors can be telling of vulnerabilities - something that could be valuable to an attacker.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't render those elements at all. Render only login form on one page and that's it. Once the user is logged in, you'll redirect him to the page that has all the elements that logged user should see *aka* dashboard. Create separate pages for login and dashboard. Login should go first. After login is successful, redirect to dashboard. As we all can see, you tagged your question with `PHP` tag which tells us that you know what PHP is. PHP will surely be required for the whole story.

**Note: Don't forget to prevent opening dashboard if not logged in.**

I made a simple activity diagram that shows how simple authentication works.

[image]

Comment: what if non-logged person just type address of the 2nd page in browser?

Comment: `Note: don't forget to prevent opening dashboard if not logged in.`. If not logged in, redirect to `login.php`... otherwise proceed to `dashboard.php`.

Comment: @Spectarion So there is no safe way to do all of this on the same page ? maybe if i use php to echo these buttons instead changing their display from "none" to "block" ? that way they don't appear only if the user is logged in ?

Comment: I truly believe there is no need to combine everything in one page. It's not good for maintenance, debugging, not reusable...

Comment: @OneBeginer definitely look into a templating software like `twig` or `blade`

Answer (score 1):

You should **definitely** handle this with PHP; **not** handling this server-side would be a **huge** security vulnerability!

Once the user has successfully logged in, store their login information in a session. Then check against that session on the secure page.

Here's a small example:

```
<?php
sec_session_start(); // Optional but recommended
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
?>
  <p>Show secure content</p>
<?php
}
else {
  header("../index.php");
}
?>
```

This way, a logged-in user sees the secure content, while a non-logged-in user will be automatically redirected.

Note that PHP's [**`$_SESSION`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is insecure, and you may want to write your own truly secure one (such as the following):

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session ID
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php");
        exit();
    }
    // Gets current cookies params
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();              // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id(true);  // Regenerate the session, delete the old one
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Also should note, that the session should be validated before showing ANY secure content.

Answer (score 1):

As long as it only causes an error, who cares? At that point they are actively messing with your site, and should expect that errors would occur.

This does however highlight the importance of having rendered error messages turned off in production. If errors are giving potential attackers more information about your site then you're exposing yourself too much.

I would make sure it fails with no side effects - but no more effort is required than that.

## The exception

You shouldn't be sending any information that only authorised users have access to. By this I do not mean buttons - but actual data, be it profile or news articles available only to users.

If you're talking about buttons - then it doesn't matter. If you're talking about content - you need to hide that content server-side. If you can see anything in the rendered source code from the login page that is supposed to be secure - **it isn't.**